# How to synchronize Maven artefacts between nexus repositories (semi-)automatically?

Tags: maven, nexus

We have a Nexus repository for maven artefacts for a Java EE application on our premises. Our developers connect against this repository while doing a local build.

Yet, for a complete build we need artefacts from a customer situated Nexus repository, which is only available by manual VPN connection - and while being connected, we have no connection to our own one.

Now, what would be a good way to (at least semi-)automatically get all new artefacts from the customer site while being connected and put them into our own repository?

My idea so far was to run a Nexus locally on the machine doing the VPN connection and have it synchronize against both ours and theirs - does that sound reasonable or has any one a better idea?
How can this be scripted or configured via the Nexus web frontend so that it can synchronize with one of the 2 sides each time we are connected to one or the other network?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the problem correctly but maybe you could proxy the repository with nexus.

Comment: @drgn: See, the problem is that at the time, when the development machine needs a maven artifact which is referenced in the pom and does not have it locally, it would need the customer's Nexus providing it, but can't reach it due to separate networks. On the other, when being connected to the customer's network, the development machine is cut off, thus the build cannont be started. So what is needed, is some 2-step-mechanism, where the hub pc can move artifacts from the customer's nexus and then to our own one, depending on which side of the network is active.

Comment: I understand, but when you use a nexus to proxy another one it keep it locally. Where i work we use 2 nexus. 1 External that proxy our customer nexus (by vpn) and 1 nexus internal for our own artefact. If you use that scheme all you could do is reference both nexus in your settings.xml (if you are using maven). And when you need a new artefact provided by your customer just open your VPN. I will post an answer with another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rsync. or some other kind of "sync" software. But it would require to have access to the file system either by SSH or FTP. Also You may plug-in your vpn. Download all the artefact needed from the remote nexus. And upload them manually to your own nexus by the UI. Other solution, (stated in my comment) Is to proxy the remote nexus with your own one and only enable VPN when needed.

---

I will enhance the answer, since it lead to the right direction, in order to fit my question:

One Nexus proxying the other was a good idea, only that it needed for a local Nexus to run on the hub machine - that way and with the correct mirror setting in settings.xml, a chain of Nexus proxies could go through the VPN line. Only thing was (and that was the luck that the hub machine was as well a former developer laptop computer) that a build had to be done on the hub machine in order to pull the maven artefacts to the hub's Nexus and from there it could go further to our own.

Comment: I think the last mentioned solution will be the one. So the external Nexus you speak of, would be the one on the hub machine and could access the customer's Nexus when the VPN is on, and our internal Nexus could access the hub machine's Nexus when the VPN is off. What I need then is a sync between each of the Nexus pairs, so when the VPN is on, the Hub nexus could actively sync the customer's one (like a shadow) and the VPN is off, our Nexus could actively sync the hub machine's one. And if that could be scripted, it would be perfect.

Comment: The nexus repository may be synced with a tool called rsync (linux). The nexus must be reindexed if i'm not wrong. Let me know if you need more detailed help on that topic.

Comment: I think rsync is of no help here, since I don't have access to the customer's Nexus file system. All I have is the URL to the repository, which could be used in Maven settings when having network access.

Comment: Little impatient are you? ;-) Don't worry, I know how SO works. Your comment hint sounds promising, but it does not yet answer my question, since  it is not clear to me how both nexus would synchronize. As I said, when VPN is on, the hub machine is completely cut off from our own network and a developer machine running a maven build won't reach the customer's nexus. So I need to transfer the artefacts somehow from there to the hub and in a 2nd step from the hub to our nexus. If you can lead me to such a solution, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Lets call your Nexus A and customer Nexus B. When developer start a maven build. it should contact Nexus A which dont have the dependency. Then Nexus A will try to contact Nexus B but will fail because the VPN connection is off. Then, you turn on your VPN, and start the build again. Nexus A will contact Nexus B and will store a local copy on Nexus A then will provide it to your developer. You may now turn off your VPN. Because the Nexus A stored a local copy of the artefact. You will need to repeat this procedure each time a new artefact is needed. My apologies if I sounded impatient :)

Comment: The point is, that Nexus A will never ever see Nexus B, since the VPN only permits connection to one of the 2 sides. That's why I thought of the hub machine, which controls the VPN connection, acting as a 2 doors floodgate, first talking with Nexus A and then with Nexus B.

Comment: In my solution Nexus A MUST be able to reach Nexus B. Since it use the proxy feature of nexus. Then you could script the sync with nexus rest API. Take a look at it, you can probably list, download and upload with it, which should be enough to script !